# CloseApplication causes ICE105

Tags: wix

I have a `wxs` intended for [single-package authoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2"/>
<Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1"/>
```

By default, the install is per-user, which is exactly what I want. However, when I tried to add a [`CloseApplication` element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html) like this:

```
<util:CloseApplication Target="DisplayProfilesGui.exe" CloseMessage="yes" />
```

Then the package now fails validation:

```
ICE105: 3073 contains msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate execution option. This is invalid for a per user application.
```

I *want* `CloseApplication` to use impersonation, and from what I can tell [from the docs](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html) it *will* use impersonation (since I'm specifying `CloseMessage` and not `ElevatedCloseMessage`).

Is there a way to fix this warning and still use `CloseApplication` in my per-user install?

Answer (score 1):

The custom action behind `CloseApplication` decides at runtime whether to schedule the deferred custom action, so it's always included in the package along with the impersonated one. Feel free to [file a feature request](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues) to move the deferred custom action scheduling to build time (should be doable). You could also skip ICE105 using the `-sice` switch or `SuppressIces` MSBuild property.